# VBA issue, affectation of values to an excel column

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to develop a function in excel via VBA, i write the syntax below, but it's always wrong(i don't know why)!the message of error says: **Else
Cells.Value(i, 2) not correct**, please if there is a problem in the syntax help me to correct it

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
   While Cells(i, 1).Value <> 0
      If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then 
      Cells(i, 2).Value = 0
      Else
      Cells(i, 2).Value
      End If
    i = i + 1
   Wend
```

Comment: Move `Cells(i, 2).Value = 0` to a new line.

Comment: sorry for my way of expression i hope you understand the problem im trying to describe :)

Comment: thank you #BigBen ,it works but it shows me another problem in "Else
      Cells(i, 2).Value", do you have any idea?

Comment: Well you need to assign something: `Cells(i, 2).Value = "something"`. Or if you want to do nothing, get rid of `Else` and `Cells(i, 2).Value`.

Comment: thank you very much, it works this time